# Derivatives of these two functions of $x$ containing sine and exponential functions

Tags: derivatives

Can you help me with getting the derivatives of the following two functions please. 
\begin{gather*}
f_1(x)=3^{\sin x}5^{\cos x} \\
f_2(x)=e^{x^2}+\sin^2 x.
\end{gather*}

It is too complicated for me. Could someone provide me with some direction. Thank you.

Comment: For $f_1$, try taking a logarithm first. For $f_2$, use chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ll walk you through the second one and let you try the first one again on your own.

We have $f_2(c)=e^{x^2}+\sin^2x$. A sum can always be differentiated one term at a time, so let’s concentrate on differentiating $e^{x^2}$. The rule for differentiating an exponential is pretty easy:

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^u=e^u\frac{du}{dx}\;.$$

In other words, you get the same exponential back again, but multiplied by the derivative of the exponent. Here $u=x^2$, so $\frac{du}{dx}=2x$, and

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{x^2}=e^{x^2}\cdot(2x)=2xe^{x^2}\;.$$

Now we’ll deal with $\sin^2x$. Remember that this notation really means $(\sin x)^2$, so we’re differentiating a power:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin x)^2=(2\sin x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\sin x\;.$$

Since the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$, we can finish the differentiation to get

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin x)^2=(2\sin x)(\cos x)=2\sin x\cos x\;.$$

Now just add the pieces:

$$f_2'(x)=2xe^{x^2}+2\sin x\cos x\;.$$

Differentiations may sometimes be *long*, but they’re never really complicated: you can always do them one step at a time, following pretty mechanical rules.